# Open Babel can't convert from mol2 to png because Cairo library is not loaded

Tags: png, homebrew, openbabel

I first installed Open Babel through brew. When I tried to run the command: "obabel -:"CC(=O)Cl" -opng -O mymol.png", I got this error message: " Open Babel Error  in PNG Format
  PNG2Format not found. Probably the Cairo library is not loaded." I then proceeded to use brew to uninstall Open Babel. Then, I installed Cairo with brew and then installed Open Babel with brew again. Still though, I try to create a PNG output and it gives me the same error message. I just do not know what's going on??

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found that when using brew to install open-babel, I do not need to install Cairo in a separate step. The open-babel formula includes a '--with-cairo’ option that installs all the required dependencies, including Cairo.

Here is how I installed open-babel with Cairo support:

```
$ brew install --with-cairo open-babel
```